# Object is not null, and then it is null

Tags: java, null, constraints

So I have this test class, I'm very clearly setting the constraints in my Deck object, but it ends up being null. Why is it doing this? I can't figure it out

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import java.awt.*;

class DeckTester
{
    public DeckTester()
    {
        JFrame fr = new JFrame();
        fr.setDefaultCloseOperation(fr.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        fr.setSize(640,480);
        fr.setLocation(300,200);
        CardTable table = new CardTable();
        table.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        Stack faceupPile = new Stack(0,-.25,true);
        faceupPile.setStackRules(Stack.GRAB_FROM_TOP|Stack.FACEUP);
        table.add(faceupPile);
        StackRuleConstraints src = new StackRuleConstraints();
        src.dropPile = faceupPile;
        Deck deck = new Deck();
        deck.setStackRules(deck.getStackRules(),src);
        table.add(new Deck());
        fr.add(table);
        fr.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[]args)
    {
        new DeckTester();
    }
}
```

Here are the Deck, Stack, and StackRuleConstraints classes. I have

```
System.out.println("constraints are "+(ruleConstraints!=null?"not null":"null"));
```

included in the mouseReleased method of variable ml and setStackRules method.

...

```
  import java.awt.Color;

  public class Deck extends Stack
  {   
     public Deck()
     {
        this(false);
     }

     public Deck(boolean includeJokers)
     {
        super(0,-.25,true);
        for(int rank = Card.ACE; rank <= Card.KING; rank++)
        {
           for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
           {
              int suit = (int)Math.pow(2,i);
              add(new Card(rank,suit));
           }
        }
        if(includeJokers)
        {  
           add(new Card(Card.JOKER,Card.RED));
           add(new Card(Card.JOKER,Card.BLACK));
        }
        setStackRules(GRAB_FROM_TOP|DRAW_PILE);
        shuffle();
     }
  }
```

...

```
  import java.awt.Graphics;
  import java.awt.Graphics2D;
  import java.util.Collections;
  import java.util.ArrayList;
  import java.awt.Container;
  import java.awt.Component;
  import java.awt.FlowLayout;
  import java.awt.Color;
  import java.awt.Dimension;
  import java.awt.RenderingHints;
  import java.awt.Color;
  import java.awt.Point;
  import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
  import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
  import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;

  public class Stack extends Container
  {
     public static final int GRAB_FROM_TOP = 1;
     public static final int GRAB_BY_GROUP = 2;
     public static final int ASCENDING = 4;
     public static final int DESCENDING = 8;
     public static final int SAME_SUITS = 16;
     public static final int ALTERNATING_COLORS = 32;
     public static final int DRAW_PILE = 64;
     public static final int RECEPTACLE = 128;
     public static final int FACEDOWN = 256;
     public static final int FACEUP = 512;

     private int rules = 0;
     protected ArrayList<Card> cards = new ArrayList<Card>();
     protected boolean accessible;
     private double xOffset;
     private double yOffset;
     private Color outlineColor;
     protected static Card selectedCard = null; //BOOKMARK we have to grab cards by the group, thus this will probably need to be a Card array
     protected static Card[] groupedCards = null;
     private Point clickLoc;
     protected static int xOrigin;
     protected static int yOrigin;
     protected static int mouseX;
     protected static int mouseY;
     protected static Point cardOrigin;
     protected static boolean dragging = false;
     protected static double draggedCardXOffset;
     protected static double draggedCardYOffset;
     private ArrayList<Card> cardsToRemove = new ArrayList<Card>();
     protected StackRuleConstraints ruleConstraints = null;

     private MouseAdapter ml = new MouseAdapter()
     {
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e)
        {
           if((rules&RECEPTACLE)>0)return;
           xOrigin = e.getXOnScreen();
           yOrigin = e.getYOnScreen();

           for(int i = 0; i < cards.size(); i++)
           {
              if(cards.get(i).getLocationOnScreen().x<xOrigin
                 &&xOrigin<cards.get(i).getLocationOnScreen().x+50
                 &&cards.get(i).getLocationOnScreen().y<yOrigin
                 &&yOrigin<cards.get(i).getLocationOnScreen().y+70)
                 {
                    cardsToRemove.clear();
                    groupedCards = null;
                    if(i!=cards.size()-1)
                    {
                       if((rules&GRAB_FROM_TOP)>0)continue;
                       if((rules&GRAB_BY_GROUP)>0&&i!=cards.size()-1)
                       {
                          groupedCards = new Card[cards.size()-1-i];
                          for(int j = i+1; j < cards.size(); j++)
                          {
                             groupedCards[j-i-1] = cards.get(j);
                             cardsToRemove.add(cards.get(j));
                          }
                       }
                    }
                    if((rules&DRAW_PILE)==0&&!cards.get(i).isSelected())//if the card you clicked is facedown
                    {
                       if(i!=cards.size()-1)return; //if it's not the top card, return
                       else //otherwise flip it faceup
                       {
                          cards.get(i).setSelected(true);
                          repaint();
                          return;
                       }
                    }
                    cardOrigin = cards.get(i).getLocationOnScreen();
                    selectedCard = cards.get(i);
                    draggedCardXOffset = xOffset;
                    draggedCardYOffset = yOffset;
                 }
           }
        }

        public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e)
        {
           if(!dragging&&selectedCard!=null)
           {
              remove(selectedCard);
              for(Card c: cardsToRemove)System.out.println("moving "+c.toString());
              if(cardsToRemove.size()>0)for(int i = 0; i < cardsToRemove.size(); i++){remove(cardsToRemove.get(i));}
              dragging = true;
           }
           mouseX = e.getXOnScreen();
           mouseY = e.getYOnScreen();
           getParent().repaint();
        }

        public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e)
        {
           System.out.println("constraints are "+(ruleConstraints!=null?"not null":"null"));
           if(dragging)ADDING_CARD_TO_STACK:
           {
              for(Component c: getParent().getComponents())
              {
                 if(c instanceof Stack
                    &&e.getXOnScreen()>c.getLocationOnScreen().x
                    &&e.getXOnScreen()<c.getLocationOnScreen().x+c.getWidth()
                    &&e.getYOnScreen()>c.getLocationOnScreen().y
                    &&e.getYOnScreen()<c.getLocationOnScreen().y+c.getHeight()
                    &&selectedCard!=null
                    &&(((Stack)c).rules&DRAW_PILE)==0)
                    {
                       ((Stack)c).add(selectedCard);
                       if(groupedCards!=null)for(Card card: groupedCards)((Stack)c).add(card);
                       break ADDING_CARD_TO_STACK;
                    }
              }
              if(dragging&&selectedCard!=null){add(selectedCard);if(groupedCards!=null)for(Card card: groupedCards)add(card);}
           }
           else {if((rules&DRAW_PILE)>0&&ruleConstraints!=null){System.out.println("criteria met");if(ruleConstraints.dropPile!=null){remove(selectedCard);ruleConstraints.dropPile.add(selectedCard);}}}
           selectedCard = null;
           groupedCards = null;
           cardsToRemove.clear();
           dragging = false;
           getParent().repaint();
        }
     };

     public Stack()
     {
        this(true);
     }

     public Stack(boolean accessible)
     {
        this(0,0,accessible);
     }

     public Stack(double xOffset, double yOffset, boolean accessible)
     {
        this(new Color(5,250,10),xOffset,yOffset,accessible);
     }

     public Stack(Color outlineColor, double xOffset, double yOffset, boolean accessible)
     {
        super();
        this.xOffset = xOffset;
        this.yOffset = yOffset;
        this.accessible = accessible;
        this.outlineColor = outlineColor;
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension((int)(50+Math.max(2,Math.abs(getXOffset())*cards.size())),(int)(70+Math.max(2,.25*54)+(getYOffset()<0?0:getYOffset()*cards.size()))));
        addMouseListener(ml);
        addMouseMotionListener(ml);
     }

     public void setStackRules(int rules)
     {
        this.rules = rules;
     }

     public void setStackRules(int rules, StackRuleConstraints constraints)
     {
        this.rules = rules;
        ruleConstraints = constraints;
        System.out.println("constraints are "+(ruleConstraints!=null?"not null":"null"));
     }

     public int getStackRules()
     {
        return rules;
     }

     public Color getOutlineColor()
     {
        return outlineColor;
     }

     public void setOutlineColor(Color c)
     {
        outlineColor = c;
        repaint();
     }

     public void setXOffset(double xOffset)
     {
        this.xOffset = xOffset;
     }

     public void setYOffset(double yOffset)
     {
        this.yOffset = yOffset;
     }

     public double getXOffset()
     {
        return xOffset;
     }

     public double getYOffset()
     {
        return yOffset;
     }


     public void shuffle()
     {
        Collections.shuffle(cards);
        super.removeAll();
        for(int i = 0; i < cards.size();i++)super.add(cards.get(i));
     }

     public void remove(Card c)
     {
        cards.remove(c);
        super.remove(c);
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension((int)(50+Math.max(2,Math.abs(getXOffset())*cards.size())),(int)(70+Math.max(2,.25*54)+(getYOffset()<0?0:getYOffset()*cards.size()))));
        setSize(getPreferredSize());
        repaint();
     }

  //    public Card drawCard()
  //    {
  //       if(cards.size()>0)
  //       {
  //          Card c = cards.get(cards.size()-1);
  //          remove(c);
  //          cards.remove(cards.size()-1);
  //          return c;
  //       }
  //       else return null;
  //    }

     public void add(Card c)
     {
        cards.add(c);
        super.add(c);
        if((rules&FACEUP)>0)c.setSelected(true);
        if((rules&FACEDOWN)>0)c.setSelected(false);
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension((int)(50+Math.max(2,Math.abs(getXOffset())*cards.size())),(int)(70+Math.max(2,.25*54)+(getYOffset()<0?0:getYOffset()*cards.size()))));
        setSize(getPreferredSize());
        repaint();
     }

     @Override
     public void paint(Graphics gi)
     {
        Graphics2D g = (Graphics2D)gi;
        g.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
        g.setColor(outlineColor);
        g.fillRoundRect(0,(int)(.25*54)-2,52,72,10,10);
        g.setColor(getParent().getBackground());
        g.fillRoundRect(2,(int)(.25*54),48,68,5,5);
        double x = 1;
        double y = .25*54-1;
        for(int i = 0; i < cards.size(); i++)
        {
           cards.get(i).setLocation((int)x,(int)y);
           g.drawImage(cards.get(i).getCurrentImage(),(int)x,(int)y,null);
           x+=xOffset;
           y+=yOffset;
        }
        super.paint(g);
     }
  }
```

...

```
  public class StackRuleConstraints
  {
     public Stack dropPile = null;

     public StackRuleConstraints()
     {

     }
  }
```

The output is

`constraints are not null`

`constraints are null`

Comment: Why was this question down-voted? That ruins users reputations, and it wasn't a malformed question. When someone has an issue they come here obviously because they missed the answer, regardless if it was obvious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are creating a deck, but then adding a new one to the table:

```
Deck deck = new Deck();
deck.setStackRules(deck.getStackRules(),src);
table.add(new Deck());
```

It should be

```
table.add(deck);
```